# DolphinDB: How to count the number of columns with the same data as the first column based on each row?

Tags: static, compare, dolphindb

Suppose there is a table t as follows:

```
t = table(1..5 as col1, 1 2 3 3 5 as col2, 1 3 2 4 5 as col3)
```

I want to compare whether the data in “col2“ and “col3“ is the same as that in “col1“ and count the frequency of the same data based on each row. Take the first row of table t as an example, since the data of both “col2“ and “col3“ equals that of “col1“, the frequency should be 2.

Answer (score 0):

Row-based functions can be used to calculate on rows. In this case, compare whether "col1" equals "col2" or "col3", and return true if so. Then use the `rowSum` function to calculate the sum of true Boolean values for each row. Here is an example script:

```
t = table(1..5 as col1, 1 2 3 3 5 as col2, 1 3 2 4 5 as col3)
select *，rowSum(each(eq{t.values()[0]}，t.values()[1:3])) from t
```

Or

```
select *,rowSum(t.values()[0] == matrix(t.values()[1:3])) from t
```